# How to get Date Month and Year Number using dataSet.Tables query

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I was using a Linq Query in getting Month and Year Number values and my query is:

```
brgData.Where(t => t.reportingDate != null && t.reportingDate.Value.Month == month4 && t.reportingDate.Value.Year == month4Year).Sum(t => t.TranCount)
```

I want to implement the same logic using dataSet.Tables query, however I'm getting an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Value'.

Below is my query:

```
var transactionMnth4 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) != null && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()).Value.Month == month4 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()).Value.Year == month4Year)
           .GroupBy(a => 1)
           .Select(d =>
               d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))
           ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Remove `.Value`, a `DateTime` is not a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Is the DataSet strongly- or loosely typed?

Comment: It's in a string Select format

Comment: What is `dataSet`? How do you fill it? If it's a strongly typed DataSet you don't need `AsEnumerable` which converts it into a loosely typed because you get `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Does `dataSet` have a property `dataBridge`?

Comment: DataSet dataSet = GetPlainBrgDataSQLite(ProgramID);

Comment: Removing .Value worked.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.Value`, a `DateTime` is not a `Nullable<DateTime>`

```
var transactionMnth4 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Where(a => a["reportingDate"].ToString() != null 
        && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()).Month == month4 
        && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()).Year == month4Year)
   .GroupBy(a => 1)
   .Select(d =>
       d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))
   ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But if that column is actually a nullable `DateTime` column you don't need to convert it to a string in the first place. Then use the `Field` extension method:

```
var transactionMnth4 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Where(a => a.Field<DateTime?>("reportingDate").HasValue 
           && a.Field<DateTime?>("reportingDate").Value.Month == month4 
           && a.Field<DateTime?>("reportingDate").Value.Year == month4Year)
   .GroupBy(a => 1)
   .Select(d => d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount")))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

(not sure what you're summing there, though)